# ajax get request for js (js.erb in rails) - url/naming problems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery

in my profile/index.html.haml,
I have

```
:javascript
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#clickablething').click(function() {
      $.get('/profile', {**passed in json data**}, null, 'script');
    })
  });
```

which calls my `index.js.erb` when the click event occurs.  However I'm wondering how I can rename the `.js.erb` file.  Only `/profile` (or `./profile`, or `profile`) works to call specifically `index.js.erb`. If I rename the file `profile.js.erb` it doesn't work (I've tried setting the url to `profile.js`, `profile.js.erb`, `profile/profile.js` and other variations, but those are all invalid requests as firebug shows.

Basically I would like to name `index.js.erb` `profile.js.erb` or something else, and am wondering how to refer to it in my `get` call.

Thanks!!

edit: This is really important for me now, since I have 2+ js.erb files I would like to call via ajax GET when different events happen.  So I can't just stick to one index.js.erb.  How do I do this? What's the ajax call for `onescript.js.erb` and `anotherscript.js.erb`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to put everything in index.js.erb and only run the sections i need conditionally...

Answer (score 0):

The index action renders by default index.html.haml or index.js.erb, but you can tell it to render profile.js.erb if that is what you want...

Your get action has nothing to do with the file rails serves. Change your controller to something like this:

```
def index
    respond_to do |format|
        format.js { render 'profile/profile' }
    end    
end
```

Comment: but what if i want it to make an ajax GET to get profile.js.erb when I click something, and make a different request to anotherscript.js.erb when I click something else?

Comment: profile.js.erb and anotherscript.js.erb are just files... Rails will not serve them up to the world in any way.. except if you have controller actions which render them. So to answer your question you first need to set up a new route and a new action controller just like the one above which servers anotherscript.js.erb instead. Then you can do an ajax to the controller action which is mapped in your routes. Index is a default route for your controller, you should define another. A very good guide [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html).

Answer (score 0):

Did you have correct route for /profile/profile.js?

```
resources :profiles
  get :profile
end
```

After do that, you can try again.